# Rewarded video ads-Failed to load ad error code 3 admob

Tags: android

I  stuck for 3 days on implementing AdMob Rewarded Video , the code is completely find but when I launch the app it's said "onRewardedVideoAdFailedToLoad" and getting error code 3 and ad won't display kindly please help me what i do?

Comment: Did you find the solution ? i am stuck on the same thing. Also created a mediation group with 3 networks. still getting this error of no fill.

Comment: Please wait for 1-2 days after publishing your app.

Answer (score 11):

Error code is 3 stand for the ad request was successful, but no ad was returned due to lack of ad inventory.

The document is here https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/ads/AdRequest#ERROR_CODE_NO_FILL

You can implement this small function to get the knowledge of error code.

```
   private int getAdMobErrorCode(SampleErrorCode errorCode) {
    switch (errorCode) {
        case BAD_REQUEST:
        return AdRequest.ERROR_CODE_INVALID_REQUEST;
    case NETWORK_ERROR:
        return AdRequest.ERROR_CODE_NETWORK_ERROR;
    case NO_INVENTORY:
        return AdRequest.ERROR_CODE_NO_FILL;
    case UNKNOWN:
    default:
        return AdRequest.ERROR_CODE_INTERNAL_ERROR;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue, it was caused because I was trying to load real adds while still on development. So I fixed it by using this .addTestDevice("device Id provided by admob on the logs") just before building my request. You can check [this](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/test-ads) for more info about adding test devices.

Answer (score 2):

Google throws error code 3 for many reasons.
One of the official reason is that there is no Ads in the Google Server.
This Error is also caused when you change your Keystore after implementing the Ad to previous Keystore. If you have changed your Keystore then you can fix this error just by replacing the Ad Unit.
Still if you find this error then you don't worry and upload the App in Play Store or App Store and Connect your App With Admob.
Hope this was Helpful for you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to generate a signed apk for ads to begin to be served, otherwise you will get error code 3.