# Ad failed to load : 3

Tags: android, admob

I have published an app. 1 month ago I could see advertising, but now I don't see it. AdMob was working perfectly fine at the beginning. But for one week I'm only receiving an Error:

> `Ad failed to load : 3`

Comment: Lack of ad inventory, more in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49547972/13772418)

Answer (score 1):

Please update the app signing key with the latest one provided by Google Play App signing (SHA1 and SHA256 keys).
You will have to add that key into the Firebase project. Then Link your Firebase account with your Adsense and wait for few hours.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that this happens when I show the GDPR consent for the European Union to the user, and the user chooses to accept only the essential cookies.

I would expect to get non-user related data then, but this does not happen for me, no ad appears in this case, instead this error message.

Comment: for more details, see also https://groups.google.com/g/google-admob-ads-sdk/c/UcveWmtBm4Q/m/Fb-rtp2vAwAJ