# Failed to load ad 3

Tags: android, admob, ads

I am using already working AdunitId and error code 3.
Other apps with this AduntId is working fine.
Here is my code.

```
adView = (AdView)findViewById(R.id.ads);
adrequest =new AdRequest.Builder().build ;
adView.loadAd(adrequest);
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Rewarded video ads-Failed to load ad error code 3 admob](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43884621/rewarded-video-ads-failed-to-load-ad-error-code-3-admob)

Comment: @JeneaVranceanu there are no solutions for this question in the link you provided

Answer (score 0):

**Error Code 3 : ERROR_CODE_NO_FILL**

Description (Dev Docs Link) : The ad request was successful, but no ad was returned due to lack of ad inventory.

Why is  it Happening : Advertisers can target specific regions, platforms and user profiles based on business relevance, which can sometimes result in lower availability of Ads for a particular region or user profile. Error code suggests that the implementation is correct, and that the Ad Request was not filled because of lack of availability of a suitable Ad at that particular instant of time when an Ad Request was sent from the app.

> If you are getting this error, then your code is correct. The issue is that AdMob does not always have an ad to return for every request. This may happen particularly if you have just registered your AdMob publisher ID, as it takes some time and multiple requests before the new ID starts returning ads.
>
> Another reason your fill rate may be low is that you don't have AdSense backfill enabled, or you have filtered out some ads. Check your app settings to see if that is the case.

[Error code 3 docs](https://support.google.com/admob/thread/3494603?hl=en)

You can add a .setTestMode(True) so that you know its working

You can find about how with a search

Comment: Other apps that using this adunitid is working fine

Comment: @deva is because of the lack of ad inventory.

Comment: You can also add a test device https://developers.google.com/admob/android/test-ads incase the app is trying to load real ads @deva

Comment: Its load test ads

Comment: Does it load test ads

Comment: Yes its load test ad

Comment: Then the code is working fine. If you deploy the app to store it will work ok

Comment: The app is not load real ads if not deploy to store?

Comment: @deva according to the docs it seems to be that. Also the ads don't load because there is lack of ads in the inventory. Check my answer on what could be done. Otherwise your code is correct.

Comment: Other app using that adunit id is loading real ads

Comment: as i said the reason behind this not an error on your part https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33566485/failed-to-load-ad-3 try the method on this link @deva